# COM-Interface for accessing file information (title, subject, author)?

Tags: winapi, file, shell, properties

On NTFS, any file can have extended file information based on an Alternate Data Stream. Explorer displays this as a tab in the file properties dialog.
I am quite sure there is a COM-Interface for reading/modifying this information, but I seem to be unable to come up with the right terms for my search.

Can anyone give me a short pointer?
Thanks in advance!

Best regards,
Martin

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that alternate data streams are used for this.  It's more likely based on what Microsoft calls [Structured Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380369%28VS.85%29.aspx) (which used to be called [compound file binary  format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_File_Binary_Format)).

Comment: Hi, why can I add it to any (empty) file as well? I'm quite sure it is saved as ADS in this case, but I need to confirm. But I think the IStorage interface could be the pointer in the right direction.

Comment: I reread your post more carefully, and you are correct.  I thought the dialog was from a Word document and that's why I pointed you towards Structured Storage.  Sorry!